# SQL Sum and Count

Tags: sql, database, sum, average

I have the following data set.

```
[Date Recorded]             [VoteID]  [User]
[2012-07-20 00:00:00.000]   [2]       [A]
[2012-07-20 00:00:00.000]   [3]       [B]
[2012-07-20 00:00:00.000]   [4]       [C]
[2012-07-24 00:00:00.000]   [1]       [A]
[2012-07-24 00:00:00.000]   [1]       [B]
```

How can I get it to count the vote sum.
If we look at 2012-07-24 there are 2 users who recorded a vote of [1] so how can I get these two users to add up.
So it would look something like

```
[Date Recorded]             [VoteID]  [Count]
[2012-07-20 00:00:00.000]   [2]       [1]
[2012-07-20 00:00:00.000]   [3]       [1]
[2012-07-20 00:00:00.000]   [4]       [1]
[2012-07-24 00:00:00.000]   [1]       [2]
```

I have a Guid for the UserID as well as the VoteID.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Group on `[Date Recorded]` and `VoteID`:

```
SELECT [Date Recorded], VoteID, COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [Date Recorded], VoteID
```

The GUID for your user who voted is irrelevant since you just want to know *how many* people voted a certain way on a given date; you don't need specific user details in this aggregate.

Comment: So now we just need to see if it's my table or your table... :)

Answer (score 7):

Use `GROUP BY` to group by *both* the date and id column, then `COUNT` up the results in each group:

```
SELECT [Date Recorded], VoteID, COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY [Date Recorded], VoteID
```